# I am running some PHP on Apache using XAMPP, It works perfectly on my friends mac but doesn't work on my Windows 8

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Is there any particular reason this happens that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use absolute paths like `/tmp` for e.g.? Take a look at the error logs, you should find the answer quickly.

Comment: Yes I use `/index`? This is what it says in the error log `[core:notice] [pid 1448:tid 404] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'`

Comment: @JohnMcDonagh22 I meant absolute file paths, sorry for this misunderstanding. A 404 error is known for "not found" status. Do you have any rewrite rules in your .htacces file, but have not enable your mod_rewrite module?

Comment: So I should use something like `C:\xampp\index`? I am using rewrite but I have it enabled in the `httpd.conf`file. Is that the correct place to have it?

Comment: Take a look at your phpinfo() output to see if the module is enabled and look here for enabling it: http://www.lancelhoff.com/enabling-htaccess-in-apache-on-windows/

Comment: phpinfo() says that it is one of the loaded modules.

Comment: Please provide some piece of code and also the php error log entries

Comment: `[27-Mar-2014 21:26:14 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 2.0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\includes\classes\cache.class.php on line 86
[27-Mar-2014 21:26:14 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: index in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\includes\classes\cache.class.php on line 86

[27-Mar-2014 21:26:14 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\includes\classes\cache.class.php on line 137` this is what is in the php error log